# .htaccess to redirect everything to index.php, but keep a copy of the website in a subdirectory

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have a simple .htaccess file. I want it to redirect everything that's not a file or directory to index.php. I am keeping another copy of the website in the subfolder `may9-new` (with the same .htaccess file copied into that directory). But the problem is, I can access `www.example.com/may9-new` successfully, but if I go to `www.example.com/may9-new/anything` it appears that I am seeing the version of the site in the root folder. Here's the .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/may9-new
RewriteRule ^([^?]*)$ /index.php?path=$1 [NC,L,QSA] 
</IfModule>
```

I barely know anything when it comes to .htaccess, so bear with me. I learned that `RewriteCond` is a condition for which `RewriteRule` should take place. So I tried to write a condition that the path can't start with `/may9-new`. This `RewriteCond` works only for `www.example.com/may9-new` and not if there are more slashes added.

Can someone please help me figure out the correct rule?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Don't use absolute path `/` in target. This is the .htaccess you can keep in root as well as in sub-directory:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L,NC]

# If the request is not for a valid directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# If the request is not for a valid file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# route to index.php in current directory
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?path=$1 [L,QSA] 
</IfModule>
```

Comment: I think you're onto something, but I'm getting an Internet Server Error with this .htaccess file. **Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator and inform them of the time the error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.**

Comment: Does `may9-new` not have an `index.php`? Can you check Apache error.log to see what the error is for 500 error

Comment: It definitely has one and it works. But the other pages don't work. Let me figure out how to check the error log.

Comment: It says `[Tue May 19 03:40:38 2015] [10528350] [core:error] [client 172.56.28.46:45305] AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.` The weird thing is, this site with its .htaccess file works on a different domain hosted by Dreamhost (using godaddy for this one).

Comment: Did you try my updated answer? `Request exceeded the limit of 10` can only be there if there is no `index.php` in the current directory.

Comment: I am positive that I've always had an index.php file in both directories. I tried your answer just now and I'm getting the same error as before.

Comment: That means error is due to some other rule somewhere else. Rename this `/may9-new/.htaccess` and retest. Also try commenting `DirectoryIndex` line for testing

Comment: Okay so now I have your version in the `may9-new` directory, and I have 5ervant's version in my root directory. The result is my original problem still exists---everything in the `may9-new` directory appears that it is the root directory's version, except for the "directory" file (`www.example.com/may9-new` works, but not `www.example.com/may9-new/something`)

Comment: No don't do that. Keep above `.htaccess` content exactly as shown in root and don't keep any .htaccess in `/may9-new/` then see what behavior you get.

Comment: I still get an internet server error when I do that for all files except index

Comment: That proves that you have some other rule/directive sitting somewhere since `/may9-new/` doesn't have a .htaccess. Now create `/may9-new/.htaccess` with just one line `RewriteEngine On` and retest.

Comment: Okay did that, but I still have the same original problem. `www.example.com/may9-new/page` still looks like `www.example.com/page`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78219/discussion-between-anubhava-and-nick-manning).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to based your configuration to your host system. Try to check these:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/may9-new(.*)
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /index.php?path=$1 [NC,QSA]
```

You can also contact your hosting provider about this issue as you've said:

> The weird thing is, this site with its .htaccess file works on a
>   different domain hosted by...

Do you also have the same *.htaccess* file in your *"may9-new"* sub-folder?

> I am keeping another copy of the website in the subfolder may9-new
>   (**with the same .htaccess file copied into that directory**).

If you also have, then there maybe a conflict, try to modify the *.htaccess* file of your sub-folder:

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /may9-new/index.php?path=$1 [NC,QSA]
```

Comment: Turns out the .htaccess file in may9-new had the wrong filename, but I updated your edits and changed the name back, and now I'm getting some kind of infinite redirect loop...the same internet server error mentioned in the other answer.

Comment: @NickManning Remember to always check if the file is not exist with `!-f` and `!-d`. Try this in your sub-folder: `RewriteRule ^/may9-new/(.+)$ /may9-new/index.php?path=$1 [NC,QSA]`

Comment: With this rule I get the same original problem...it appears to show the version of the site in the root folder. When I switch back, it's an infinite redirect.

Comment: @NickManning You need to add this directive in the root: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/?may9-new(.*)` Is there any _.htaccess_ file on your system?

Comment: That condition was already added. I'm using godaddy...there is currently just one .htaccess file in the root, exactly what you told me to put. It works, just as my original file worked, but I still have the same problem in the subdirectory.

Comment: @NickManning Try to contact your hosting provider for that.. Provide your _".htaccess"_ files, tell them that your configuration works on different host. But keep note, when redirection happened, always clear your cache and restart the browser before retesting..